# How to plot points on several concentric circles in sequence?

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry, matlab-figure, angle

I want to plot several points on several concentric circles just like this:

[image: sample image]

The number of points on different circles are same and to be determined. The difference of radius are same.

But I face the problem that if I want to use the `for` function, I define `i = 1:total number of points`. I don't know how to select correct angle value. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
R_steplength = 1; %difference of radius
angle_point = 20; %total number of points on one circle
max_R = 4; %outer radius of circle
central_x = 1; % origin of concentric circle
central_y = 1;

total_circle_points = (max_R/R_steplength) * angle_point; %calculate total
points
fin_x= zeros(1, total_circle_points); %define output points position
fin_y = zeros(1, total_circle_points);

for i = 1:total_circle_points
    for j = 1:angle_point
        if rem(i+1, 20)~= 1
            k = floor(i/20);
            angles = linspace(0,2*pi,angle_point);
            fin_x(i) = R_steplength*(k+1)*cos(angles(j))+central_x;
            fin_y(i)= R_steplength*(k+1)*sin(angles(j))+central_y;
        else
            fin_x(i) = central_x + R_steplength*(k+2);
            fin_y(i) = central_y + R_steplength*(k+2);
        end
        plot(fin_x(:),fin_y(:),'ro')
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`polarplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html) for that:

```
ax = polaraxes; % create polar axes
% calculate all points locations:
[angles,rad] = meshgrid(0:angle_point:360,1:R_steplength:max_R);
polarplot(ax,deg2rad(angles),rad,'r.') % plot all the points
ax.GridColor = 'k'; % set grid color to black
ax.GridAlpha = 1;
ax.ThetaAxis.TickValues = 10:20:360; % set radius grid between the points
ax.RAxis.TickValues = 1.5:R_steplength:(max_R+0.5); % set circles between the points
ax.RAxis.Limits = [0 max_R+0.5]; % show the outer circle
```

Here I use the axes grid to draw the circles. If this is not needed you can just write:

```
[angles,rad] = meshgrid(0:angle_point:360,1:R_steplength:max_R);
polarplot(ax,deg2rad(angles),rad,'r.') % plot all the points
```

[image: concentric circles]